# Convert duration format P0DT0H0M0S (ISO 8601 Duration Format) to hours

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duration, iso8601

I'm looking for a convenient way to convert from "ISO 8601 Duration Format" (P0DT0H0M0S) to hours.

So far I have come up with this:

```
# Example in BigQuery
SELECT
    24 * CAST(SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('P1DT2H3M44S', 'P', ''), 'DT', '-'), 'H', '-'), 'M', '-'), 'S', ''), '-')[OFFSET(0)] AS INT64)
    + CAST(SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('P1DT2H3M44S', 'P', ''), 'DT', '-'), 'H', '-'), 'M', '-'), 'S', ''), '-')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64)
    + (1/60) * CAST(SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('P1DT2H3M44S', 'P', ''), 'DT', '-'), 'H', '-'), 'M', '-'), 'S', ''), '-')[OFFSET(2)] AS INT64)
    + (1/3600) * CAST(SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('P1DT2H3M44S', 'P', ''), 'DT', '-'), 'H', '-'), 'M', '-'), 'S', ''), '-')[OFFSET(3)] AS INT64) AS HOURS
```

As you can see, my approach was to split out the numbers and multiply by 24, 1, 1/60, 1/3600 to get to hours. Can I reduce the amount of code?

> **Sample data and desired result**
> Input: 'P1DT2H3M44S' *(1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes, 44 seconds)*
> Desired output: 26.06222222222222 *(this is hours)*

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below option

```
select *,    
  (select sum(cast(val as int64) * weight)
   from unnest(regexp_extract_all(col, r'\d+')) val with offset
   join unnest([24, 1, 1/60, 1/3600]) weight with offset 
   using(offset)
  ) as hours
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Above assumes that all parts (days, hours, minutes, seconds) are present even if they are zero

If this is not a case - I doubt it is, but not sure - slight adjustment to above solution needs to be applied. let me know

Answer (score 0):

This option is slimmer than the original code but still easy to understand and modify.

```
SELECT
    'P0DT5H47M0S' AS iso_8601_duration,
    24 * CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT('P0DT5H47M0S', '[0-9]+', 1, 1) AS INT64)
    + 1 * CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT('P0DT5H47M0S', '[0-9]+', 1, 2) AS INT64)
    + (1/60) * CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT('P0DT5H47M0S', '[0-9]+', 1, 3) AS INT64)
    + (1/3600) * CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT('P0DT5H47M0S', '[0-9]+', 1, 4) AS INT64) AS Hours
```